# diff between two days, in hours

Tags: c#

I do not uderstand why the result of:

```
(DateTime.Now.Subtract(user.created_time.Value.Date)).Hours
```

is 23.

where:

> DateTime.Now is:{3/30/2010 12:00:00
>   AM}

and

> user.created_time.Value.Date is :
>   {3/24/2010 12:00:00 AM}

Does it make sense for anybody?

ps: I want to select all users created in last 72 hours so i suppose that is the way i should do...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Hours`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.hours.aspx) just gives you the hours, and ignores the other fields like days. Use [`TotalHours`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalhours.aspx) instead.

Comment: And I'm guessing the reason for the 23 has something to do with bad DST settings.

Comment: What makes you think the DST settings are bad? In Romania DST started March 28, 2010 at 3:00:00 AM.

Comment: Ok, not bad, just different. (If I had my way there wouldn't be any DST at all.)

Comment: Tell me about it, DST sucks.  Too many people think each day has 24 hours.  Doesn't affect you so badly when there is 23 hours in a day, but when you try to stuff 25 hours into something that expects 24 hours, it gets ugly.

Comment: What sucks is a Date/Time library that can't deal with DST!

Answer (score 0):

The [`Hours`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.hours.aspx) property gives you the hours component of the `TimeSpan`. Thus, if a `TimeSpan` is more than a day, `Hours` will give you only the hours part, without any full days.

You want the [`TotalHours`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalhours.aspx) instead.